# Analogue of a technique that is widely done in number theory

Tags: number-theory, summation, algebraic-number-theory

For any positive $x$, we have

$$
\sum_{n \leq x} \sum_{d | n} \varLambda(d) = \sum_{n \leq x} \varLambda(n)\lfloor\ x/n\rfloor, 
$$
where $\varLambda$ is the von-Mangoldt function.

Now, let $K$ denote a number field of degree $n$ and  $\mathcal{O}_K$ be the ring of integers of $K$. It is a fact that every non-zero proper ideal $\mathfrak{a} \subset \mathcal{O}_K$ can be written as a product of prime ideals in a unique way. The *norm* of an ideal $\mathfrak{a} \subset \mathcal{O}_K$, denoted by $N(\mathfrak{a})$, is defined as the cardinality of the quotient $\mathcal{O}_K / \mathfrak{a}$.

**Can we see the following equality which is an analogue of the above?**
$$
\sum_{N(\mathfrak{a}) \leq x} \sum_{\mathfrak{b} | \mathfrak{a}} \varLambda(\mathfrak{b}) = \sum_{N(\mathfrak{a}) \leq x} \varLambda(\mathfrak{a})\lfloor\ x/N(\mathfrak{a})\rfloor
$$

Comment: Did you try some examples, like quadratic fields?

Comment: I've tried for $K=\mathbb{Q}(i)$ and $x=6$.

Comment: Is there any ideal whose norm is equal to $3$ in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$?